# SQL Server - Determining Missing Indexes - DMVs

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am using the following query to determine missing indexes:

```
select 
    db_name(d.database_id) as DatabaseName, 
    object_name(d.object_id) TableName, 
    d.index_handle as IndexHandle,
    d.equality_columns as EqualityColumns, 
    d.inequality_columns as InequalityColumns, 
    d.included_columns as IncludedColumns, 
    d.statement as Object, 
    gs.user_seeks as PossibleUserSeeks,
    gs.user_scans as PossibleUserScans,
    gs.last_user_seek as LastPossibleUserSeek,
    gs.last_user_scan as LastPossibleUserScan,
    gs.system_seeks as PossibleSystemSeeks,
    gs.system_scans as PossibleSystemScans
from  
    sys.dm_db_missing_index_groups g
    join sys.dm_db_missing_index_group_stats gs on gs.group_handle = g.index_group_handle
    join sys.dm_db_missing_index_details d on g.index_handle = d.index_handle
where  
    d.database_id =  d.database_id and 
    d.object_id =  d.object_id And
    DB_NAME(d.database_id) = 'MESProduction'
```

My question concerns `'d.index_handle'`. MSDN describes this column as follows:  `Identifies a particular missing index. The identifier is unique across the server. index_handle is the key of this table.` If the index is missing, how can it be identified? And what does it mean when it says, "is the key of this table"?

Thanks very much.

Comment: I would assume that it is likely to be some number derived from the combination of DatabaseId, ObjectId, and recommended Columns. And by key of this table. It means primary key. i.e. it is unique.

Comment: SSC just published a great article about missing indexes and DMVs: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Indexing/64134/ .

Comment: Ah right I just looked at the index_handle on my machine and found it appears to be an auto increment column.

Comment: When the SQL Server Optimizer detects that a given query *could* benefit from an index, it will make an entry into that "missing index table" - that's the table they're talking about. Those are the potential indices that would help for certain queries - but are not necessarily beneficial for overall system performance...

Comment: @marc_s - Thank you. One of the indexes it suggests is missing is an index that does already exist. The only difference is that it's suggesting adding a covering column. Can I interpret this to mean that had the covering column existed, the index would have been used?

Comment: @Randy Minder: most likely yes - if you had the index with the included column, your query most likely would have been satisfied by looking at the index pages themselves - thus you would have saved yourself a lot of bookmark lookups (going from the index to the actual data pages to retrieve one or multiple missing columns to satisfy your query)